# how to create radio group just below on checkbox in android

Tags: android, checkbox

In my app i have created list view of checkbox in linear layout and i have created dynamic radio group of three radio button.when user click on any checkbox than radio group will be created at the end. but i want to create this radio group just below the clicked checked box. i am trying to set cursor position but not able to do.i don't have any idea what to do for this.

this is part of main.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         final ViewGroup checkboxContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_container);

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);

                checkBox.setText(Oils_and_Condiments[i]);
                checkboxContainer.addView(checkBox);

                checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) 
                    {   


                        for (int i = 0; i < Oils_and_Condiments.length; i++) {
                            String  a= (String) checkBox.getText();
                            if(a==Oils_and_Condiments[i])
                    {
                                RadioGroup rg = create_rb(i);

                                checkboxContainer.get
                    checkboxContainer.addView(rg);


                    rg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                //rg.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }




RadioGroup create_rb(int a ){
                final RadioGroup radiogp = new RadioGroup(this);
                radiogp.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
                RadioButton rb0 = new RadioButton(this);
                RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton(this);
                RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton(this);

                    rb0.setText("1KG");
                    rb0.setTextSize(10);
                rb1.setText("2KG");
                rb1.setTextSize(10);
                rb2.setText("3KG");
                rb2.setTextSize(10);
                    radiogp.addView(rb0);
                    radiogp.addView(rb1);
                    radiogp.addView(rb2);
                    //checkboxContainer.addView(radiogp);
                                return radiogp;
            }
```

Comment: you could have both the checkbox and the radiogroup in a vertical linearlayout (height = fill parent) , with the weight to 1 on both,  and make the radiogroup Visible="GONE". when checkbox is clicked, change that to visible, and it will fill the desired space under the check.

Comment: you can use addView(View child, int index) to select the exact place (index) where you want to add it